# File table with clustered index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have read through all the available documentations about file table on SQL server. One thing it has not mentioned is creating additional indexes (non-unique clustered index in my case) on a file table fixed schema.

Am I right to say it is perfectly fine to do that and it wouldn't cause any issues? If it is an issue what is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Create, Alter, and Drop FileTables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/create-alter-and-drop-filetables) topic in the SQL Server documentation (emphasis mine):

Since a FileTable has a pre-defined and fixed schema, you cannot add or change its columns. However, **you can add custom indexes, triggers, constraints, and other options to a FileTable**.

So you should be fine adding custom indexes.